# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Cloneable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I have a project where I am using spark with Scala. The Code does not give the compilation issue but when I run the code I get the below exception:-

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=49678:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/ScalaCode/CSVParser/target/scala-2.13/classes:/Users/iftekhar.khan/ScalaCode/CSVParser/lib/kotlin-reflect-sources.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/ScalaCode/CSVParser/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/ScalaCode/CSVParser/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-sources.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/ScalaCode/CSVParser/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/ScalaCode/CSVParser/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-sources.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/ScalaCode/CSVParser/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/ScalaCode/CSVParser/lib/kotlin-stdlib-sources.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/ScalaCode/CSVParser/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/ScalaCode/CSVParser/lib/kotlin-test-sources.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/ScalaCode/CSVParser/lib/kotlin-test.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.13.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.13.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.13/bundles/scalactic_2.13-3.0.8.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/aopalliance/aopalliance/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/asm/asm/jars/asm-3.1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.clearspring.analytics/stream/jars/stream-2.7.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.esotericsoftware.kryo/kryo/bundles/kryo-2.21.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.esotericsoftware.minlog/minlog/jars/minlog-1.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm/reflectasm/jars/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/bundles/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/bundles/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/bundles/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.10/bundles/jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.4.4.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/jars/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-14.0.1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.google.inject/guice/jars/guice-3.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/bundles/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.ning/compress-lzf/bundles/compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core/bundles/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json/bundles/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server/bundles/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-guice/jars/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2/jars/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2-1.9.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/jars/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.thoughtworks.paranamer/paranamer/jars/paranamer-2.6.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/chill-java/jars/chill-java-0.5.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter/chill_2.10/jars/chill_2.10-0.5.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.2.1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.10/jars/akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-remote_2.10/jars/akka-remote_2.10-2.3.11.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-slf4j_2.10/jars/akka-slf4j_2.10-2.3.11.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/jars/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/jars/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/commons-cli/commons-cli/jars/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.5.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/commons-collections/commons-collections/jars/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/jars/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/commons-digester/commons-digester/jars/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/jars/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/commons-io/commons-io/jars/commons-io-2.4.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/commons-lang/commons-lang/jars/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/commons-net/commons-net/jars/commons-net-2.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-core/bundles/metrics-core-3.1.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-graphite/bundles/metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-json/bundles/metrics-json-3.1.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/io.dropwizard.metrics/metrics-jvm/bundles/metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty/bundles/netty-3.8.0.Final.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-all/jars/netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/javax.activation/activation/jars/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/javax.inject/javax.inject/jars/javax.inject-1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/jars/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/jline/jline/jars/jline-2.14.6.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/log4j/log4j/bundles/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/net.java.dev.jets3t/jets3t/jars/jets3t-0.7.1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/net.jpountz.lz4/lz4/jars/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/net.razorvine/pyrolite/jars/pyrolite-4.9.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.py4j/py4j/jars/py4j-0.9.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.avro/avro/jars/avro-1.7.7.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.avro/avro-ipc/jars/avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.avro/avro-ipc/jars/avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.avro/avro-mapred/jars/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/jars/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/jars/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-math/jars/commons-math-2.1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-math3/jars/commons-math3-3.4.1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.curator/curator-client/bundles/curator-client-2.4.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.curator/curator-framework/bundles/curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.curator/curator-recipes/bundles/curator-recipes-2.4.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-annotations/jars/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-auth/jars/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client/jars/hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/jars/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/jars/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/jars/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-client/jars/hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/jars/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-common/jars/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.ivy/ivy/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.mesos/mesos/jars/mesos-0.21.1-shaded-protobuf.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.parquet/parquet-column/jars/parquet-column-1.7.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.parquet/parquet-common/jars/parquet-common-1.7.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.parquet/parquet-encoding/jars/parquet-encoding-1.7.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.parquet/parquet-format/jars/parquet-format-2.3.0-incubating.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.parquet/parquet-generator/jars/parquet-generator-1.7.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.parquet/parquet-hadoop/jars/parquet-hadoop-1.7.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.parquet/parquet-jackson/jars/parquet-jackson-1.7.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-catalyst_2.10/jars/spark-catalyst_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/jars/spark-core_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-launcher_2.10/jars/spark-launcher_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-common_2.10/jars/spark-network-common_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-network-shuffle_2.10/jars/spark-network-shuffle_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10/jars/spark-sql_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.spark/spark-unsafe_2.10/jars/spark-unsafe_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.xbean/xbean-asm5-shaded/bundles/xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper/jars/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/jars/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs/jars/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.3.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/jars/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-xc/jars/jackson-xc-1.8.3.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.janino/commons-compiler/jars/commons-compiler-2.7.8.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.janino/janino/jars/janino-2.7.8.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.codehaus.jettison/jettison/bundles/jettison-1.1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.servlet/orbits/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.fusesource.leveldbjni/leveldbjni-all/bundles/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-ast_2.10/jars/json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.10.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-core_2.10/jars/json4s-core_2.10-3.2.10.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-jackson_2.10/jars/json4s-jackson_2.10-3.2.10.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-util/jars/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.objenesis/objenesis/jars/objenesis-1.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.roaringbitmap/RoaringBitmap/bundles/RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.13.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scalap/jars/scalap-2.13.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/jars/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.10.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.sonatype.sisu.inject/cglib/jars/cglib-2.2.1-v20090111.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.spark-project.spark/unused/jars/unused-1.0.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.tachyonproject/tachyon-client/jars/tachyon-client-0.8.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.tachyonproject/tachyon-underfs-hdfs/jars/tachyon-underfs-hdfs-0.8.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.tachyonproject/tachyon-underfs-local/jars/tachyon-underfs-local-0.8.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.tachyonproject/tachyon-underfs-s3/jars/tachyon-underfs-s3-0.8.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.tukaani/xz/jars/xz-1.0.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.uncommons.maths/uncommons-maths/jars/uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/org.xerial.snappy/snappy-java/bundles/snappy-java-1.1.2.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/oro/oro/jars/oro-2.0.8.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/Users/iftekhar.khan/.ivy2/cache/xmlenc/xmlenc/jars/xmlenc-0.52.jar ReadCSVFile
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Cloneable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at ReadCSVFile$.main(ReadCSVFile.scala:8)
    at ReadCSVFile.main(ReadCSVFile.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Cloneable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

There is no compilation Error.

**Build.sbt**

```
name := "CSVParser"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.13.0"

libraryDependencies += ("org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.8")
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % Test

libraryDependencies++=Seq(
  "org.apache.spark"%"spark-core_2.10"%"1.6.0",
  "org.apache.spark"%"spark-sql_2.10"%"1.6.0"
)

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.13.0"
```

The entire code can be found here - https://github.com/practice09/CSVParser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Scala version 2.13 however Apache Spark has not yet been compiled for 2.13. Try changing your `build.sbt` to the following

```
name := "CSVParser"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.3",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.3",
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.8" % Test,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.8" % Test
)
```

where we downgraded to Scala 2.12.8 and upgraded to Spark 2.4.3.